# How to quickly check requires API level for xml value?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm using Android Studio to develop a project for different API levels.
So I have `res/values/styles.xml` for devices from `minSDKVersion` to 10 level and `res/values-v11/styles.xml` for deveces with 11 API level and higher.

Suppose I write the following line in `values/styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black">
```

How can I check, that `Theme.Black` is available with my `minSDKVersion`?

Comment: But... that's why you should use `-vXYZ` suffixes in your folders, to target different versions. You should already know if it is available or not.

Comment: @gnclmorais sounds like I need to open http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/R.style.html and use API level filter every time I use any xml value.

Comment: That seems like a good options. Eclipse also fires up some warnings about API incompatibilities when you are writing Java files... but I don't know if it does the same on XML files.

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio supports a variety of XML attributes in the tools namespace that enable design-time features (such as which layout to show in a fragment) or compile-time behaviors (such as which shrinking mode to apply to your XML resources).

To use these attributes, add the tools namespace to the root element of each XML file where you'd like to use them, as shown here:

```
<RootTag xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >
```

For example, you might use this because GridLayout is available only on API level 14 and higher, but you know this layout is not used for any lower versions:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:targetApi="14" >
```

or you can use version name: `tools:targetApi="jelly_bean"`

If you want your layout directries to be use in different versions, name your files as:

```
/res/layout/layout.xml - (default directries)

/res/layout-v14/layout.xml

/res/layout-v23/layout.xml

/res/layout-v28/layout.xml
```